# How to change the motd date format

Tags: ssh, motd

Every time I ssh into my server the server prints the last login date and time. But I don't like the format. For ex:

```
Last login: Sun Jan 31 12:12:13 2016 from 127.0.0.1
```

I want to to disable the message (in the config) and instead change it's location to the motd (00-header). How can I do it? Example how it should look:

```
Last login: 2016-01-31 12:12:13 from 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the related question on serverfault , [How do I edit the SSH “last login” message?](https://serverfault.com/q/598043)   , the line itself is built into the `/usr/sbin/sshd` binary. Thus to edit it it would be necessary to edit source code and recompile it yourself, which is somewhat more of a bother and more work than necessary

Confirming the results found on serverfault question

```
DIR:/xieerqi
skolodya@ubuntu:$ file /usr/sbin/sshd                                          
/usr/sbin/sshd: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=b0aaeed8d674586459d21eb2d548a848c33de3a9, stripped

DIR:/xieerqi
skolodya@ubuntu:$ strings /usr/sbin/sshd | grep -i "last login"                
Last login: %s
Last login: %s from %s
```

You can however tell `sshd` not to print message of the day and the last login (as per [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/38160) )

Open the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` with any editor, make sure if you use command line editor you use `sudo` and if GUI editor - `gksu`, for instance

```
  sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Append the following lines

```
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog no
```

You can place the following function into your `$HOME/.bashrc` file at the top

```
function ssh_login_date
 {
 if [ ! -z "$SSH_CLIENT" ]; then
   printf "Last login %s from %s \n" "$( date +%F" "%H":"%M":"%S  )" "$(echo $SSH_CLIENT|  awk '{print $1}' )"
 fi
}
```

And call the function at the end of the file

```
ssh_login_date
```

Comment: Oops, I did not mention that I wanted to disable the message and integrate it into the motd. So sorry. I updated my question to reflect what I actually wish to accomplish.

Comment: See my edit please

Comment: Could you also please tell how to use grep plus any other command to print the last login time just as the example in my question?

Comment: Well . . .it's possible to `grep` last login, but that's not the issue. Simplest way would be to add modified `date` command to your `.bashrc`.  The problem is that this shows time at the time of login to the ssh session, not the time last physical login was made, because it `sshd` ignores tty logins as far as I can see. I'm gonna make another edit, but that's as far as I can help

Comment: Edit done, please see it

Comment: Saw it. Unfortunately it doesn't help much. I still don't know how to print the last login time in format "Last login: <year-month-day>  <hour:minute:second> from <ip>". Thanks for linking that other question too!